# How to disable hardware virtualization check while installing KVM on ubuntu?

Tags: cloud, kvm, rackspace-cloud, hypervisor

My system doesn't support hardware virtualization technology. I am trying to install KVM and then Rackspace cloud package. So, how can I disable hardware virtualisation check while installation.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the hardware virtualization check you need to remove that source code and re-build the KVM kernel modules. The KVM kernel module that supports your processor (either Intel or AMD) makes the check for hardware virtualization:

```
int kvm_arch_init(void *opaque)
{
    int r;
    struct kvm_x86_ops *ops = (struct kvm_x86_ops *)opaque;

    if (kvm_x86_ops) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "kvm: already loaded the other module\n");
        r = -EEXIST;
        goto out;
    }

    if (!ops->cpu_has_kvm_support()) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "kvm: no hardware support\n");
        r = -EOPNOTSUPP;
        goto out;
    }
```

Even if you disable this check there are additional checks for hardware support in the initialization code and elsewhere.

What you can do is run the guest using QEMU, without the KVM support. The primary difference you will notice (its a big difference) is that QEMU emulation is slower than KVM hardware virtualization.

Comment: What are the other options available, if i want to build the cloud on the machines which do not support hardware virtualization? IS OpenNebula a good option to use it as a Hypervisor?

Comment: Try the Xen hypervisor running a para virtual Linux guest.

Answer (score 0):

KVM requires HW support. Even you disable the check, it won't work.

Try a pure QEMU without KVM support, which is able to run a guest in a full virtualization environment.